# Git hook to reject a push containing a submodule update?

Tags: git, git-submodules, githooks

I use gitosis to host my GIT repositories.

I want to prevent users other than the administrator (to be identified by the commiter's email) to push updates to submodules.

I tried to see if I could read a list of submodule changes via pre-receive hook, but since is a bare repo, it cannot read .gitmodules.

```
#!/bin/bash
OLDREV=$1
NEWREV=$2
unset GIT_DIR
unset GIT_WORKING_TREE
SUBS=$(git show $NEWREV:.gitmodules | sed -n "s/^.*git@repo://p")

for submod in SUBS
do
        echo $submod
done

exit 1
```

But I get:

```
remote: fatal: Path '.gitmodules' does not exist (neither on disk nor in the index).
```

Do you know how I could read the submodules commit being pushed in the pre-receive hook?

Comment: Just a note that the committer's email is not, by default, secure. Anybody can set any email address they wish. If you want to *enforce* this, you'll likely have to rely on cryptographic signatures, e.g. using a signed tag.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I'm aware of that, but I what I need in this case is to prevent my colleagues from mistakenly pushing a commit with a  submodule change. Allowing only my "user.email" to push such a commit would do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies in the way you are trying to read `OLDREV` and `NEWREF`.

Githooks don't get their arguments as you expect them to, they are written to stdin, which effectively means they are piped in.

To read them correctly you have to do something like this:

```sh
while read OLDREF NEWREF REFNAME
do
    # Work with the references ...
done
```

The `pre-push.example` hook - which you can find in every git repository - gives a good impression for this.

Answer (score 1):

For rolling your own you can hook pre-receive or update.  pre-receive gets all refs one line at a time via STDIN, update gets refs individually via args $1=ref, $2=old, $3=new.

The .gitmodules file would only be modified if somebody added a submodule, removed a submodule, or changed the remote path or name to the submodule (but not the SHA an existing submodule pointed to, which is more common).

Changes to the checked out SHA in an existing submodule would be represented as a different SHA at the path specified in the .gitmodules path entry.

so if you were to `git submodule add ../sub1 my_submodule` you would have changes to .gitmodules

```
cat .gitmodules
```

> [submodule "my_submodule"]
>       path = my_submodule
>       url = ../sub1

But you would also have a change in the tree seen via `git cat-file -p HEAD^{tree}`

Note the special "160000" file mode which signifies a submodule

> 160000 commit a07f4c5277d2b3e53e95b19156610c6dc6c28e49    my_submodule

Presuming you have a .gitmodules file present in your repo already, then you would want to not only block changes to it, but also to any of the submodules listed inside of it.

In your hook

This will print out the paths to all the submodules currently tracked

```
git cat-file -p ${old}:.gitmodules | grep path | awk -F= '{print $NF}'
```

This will print out the paths to all the files changed from old ref to new ref

```
git diff --name-only ${old}..${new}
```

Use whatever technique you like to verify that ".gitmodules" isn't in the second output, nor any of the submodule paths returned from the first command.